# unexpected result from strtotime formatting ("g:i A") with less than 4 digit argument

Tags: php

Trying to format time using strtotime but receiving unexpected results. (Running PHP 7.18) I am being prompted for more details but I can't figure how how to ask a longer question son please ignore this extra verbiage.

```
<?php;
$time = 1000;
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
# yields 10:00 AM  OK

$time = 2359;
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
# yields 11:59 PM  OK

$time = 900;
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
# expected 09:00  BUT
#yields 4:00 PM   

$time = 5;
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
# expected 00:05  BUT
#yields 4:00 PM  

$time = 0630;
echo date("gg:i A", strtotime($time));
# tentatively expected 6:30 AM BUT
#yields 4:00 PM
```

Comment: are you following the answers?

Answer (score 2):

sprintf() will do this for your expectation. The example code is :

```
<?php
$time = sprintf("%'.04d\n", 1000);
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
//yields 10:00 AM  OK

$time = sprintf("%'.04d\n", 2359);
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
// # yields 11:59 PM  OK

$time = sprintf("%'.04d\n", 900);
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
// # expected 09:00  BUT
// #yields 4:00 PM   

$time = sprintf("%'.04d\n", 5);
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
// # expected 00:05  BUT
// #yieldks 4:00 PM  

$time = sprintf("%'.04d\n", 630);
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time));
// # tentatively expected 6:30 AM BUT
// #yields 4:00 PM
```

Output is:

```
10:00 AM
11:59 PM
9:00 AM
12:05 AM
6:30 AM
```

For more Information is [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your variable `$time` should have 4 character value for time. And if you want to pass 9 oçlock then you have to pass 0900 but then it will give error that invalid literal found. So you need make them string (wrap with `$time = "9000"`).

So change your code like this:

```
$time = '1000';
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
# yields 10:00 AM  OK

$time = '2359';
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
# yields 11:59 PM  OK

$time = '0900';
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
#yields 9:00 AM OK

$time = '0005';
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time)).'<br>';
# expected 00:05  BUT
#yields 12:05 AM

$time = '0630';
echo date("g:i A", strtotime($time));  // You had "gg:i: A" so I removed one g
#yields 6:30 AM OK
```